# sum of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I define $A+B=\{a+b : a\in A, b\in B\}. $ Both are subsets of the set of real numbers.

Now does this definition say that elements of $A+B$ are simply all possible sums of any two points, one from A and the other from B? right?

If this is the definition then could any one help me to visualize or write explicitly the set $A+B$ where $A=\{n : n=1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ and $B=\{-n+ \dfrac{1}{n} : n=2,3,4,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $A+B$ is the set of all real numbers which can be written as the sum of an element of $A$ with an element of $B$.

Now, try to visualize $B$. Now translate that set one unit to the right; you'll get $1+B$. Now, translate it another unit to the right; you'll get $2+B$. And so on. In the end, put all these translations together, and you'll get $A+B$.

Comment: could you please be more explicitly?

Comment: @miosaki I'm afraid I can't.

Comment: is it finally going to be {1/n}?

Comment: @miosaki Are you asking if $A+B=\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$?

Comment: It will *not* be $\{\frac 1n\}$ because the $n$ from A and the $-k + \frac 1k$ do not need to be so that $n= k$.  What I believe @JoséCarlosSantos is try to say is $1+B =\{(1 - k) + \frac 1k\}=\{-1 + \frac 12,-2 + \frac 13, -3+\frac 14...\}$ and $2+B = \{(2-k) + \frac 1k\} =\{\frac 12, -1+\frac 13, ...\}$ and $3 + B = \{1 + \frac 12, \frac 13, -1 +\frac 14\}$ etc.  and $A + B = (1 +B) \cup (2+B) \cup (3+B) \cup..... $.

Answer (score 1):

That is what the definition says. $\forall a\in A\forall b\in B$ we have $a+b\in A+B$.

Looking at your example of $A=\{n:n=1,2,3,...\}$ and $B=\{-n+\frac{1}{n}:n=2,3,4,...\}$, we have
$$\begin{align}A+B&=\left\{n:n=1,2,3,...\right\}+\left\{-n+\frac{1}{n}:n=2,3,4,...\right\}\\&=\left\{n+\left(-k+\frac{1}{k}\right):n=1,2,3,4,...~\land~ k=2,3,4,...\right\}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$A=\{n : n=1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ and $B=\{-n+ 1/n : n=2,3,4,\dots\}$

I guess, this may help to visualize:

$C_1=-2+\dfrac{1}{2}+A=\{ n+\dfrac{1}{2}:n=-1,0,1,\dots \}$

$C_2=-3+\dfrac{1}{3}+A=\{ n+\dfrac{1}{3}:n=-2,-1,0,1,\dots \}$

$C_3=-4+\dfrac{1}{4}+A=\{ n+\dfrac{1}{4}:n=-3,-2,-1,0,1,\dots \}$

So in general, $C_{k-1}=-k+\dfrac{1}{k}+A=\{ n+\dfrac{1}{k}:n=-k+1,-k+2,\dots \}$

Hence $A+B=\bigcup_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}C_k=\left\{n+\left(-k+\dfrac{1}{k}\right):n=1,2,3,4,...~\land~ k=2,3,4,...\right\}$

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that $A+B$ would be the collection of the sums of all possible pairs.

So $A = \{n| n=1,2,3......\} = \{n|n\in \mathbb N\} = \mathbb N$.

and $B = \{-n+ \frac 1n|n= 2,3,4,....\}$

So $A+B =\{n + (-k + \frac 1k)|n= 1,2,3...., k=2,3,4,5,...\}$

$= \{(n-k) + \frac 1k|n\in \mathbb N; k \in \mathbb N; k > 1\}$

Notice $n-k: n = 1,2,...; k = 2,3,.....$ can be ... any integer.  Any negative integer $-m = 1 - (m+1)= n - k$ with $n =1$ and $k = m+1$.   $0 = 2 - 2$ with $n =2$ and $k = 2$.  Any positive integer $m = (m+2) -2$ with $n=m+2$ and $k = 2$.

So $A+B = \{m + \frac 1k| m \in \mathbb Z; k \in \mathbb N; k \ge 2; m+k > 0\}$.

$=\{m + \frac 1k|m,k \in \mathbb Z;k\ge 2; m>-k\}$

So example $17\frac 15$ will be in the set. ($17\frac 15 = 22 + (-5 + \frac 15)$).  $-7\frac 89$ will be in the set as $-7\frac 89 = 1+(-9 + \frac 19)$). etc.